# Vue lifecycle hook typescript error when invoking method

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm having trouble referencing a method in a Vue root component from a lifecycle method in typescript. I've been able to reproduce this behaviour with a toy example below:

```
import Vue from "vue";

class Game {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    constructor() {
        this.a = 3;
        this.b = 4;
    }
}

new Vue({
    el: "#calculator",
    data: {
        game: null
    },
    methods: {
        // bound to a button
        reset: function() {
            this.game = new Game();
        },
        // bound to a button
        add: function() {
            this.game.a += 1;
        }
    },
    beforeCreate() {
        this.reset();
    }
});
```

I am getting the following typescript compilation error:

> src/test.ts:28:8 - error TS2339: Property 'reset' does not exist on
>   type 'Vue'.
>
> 28    this.reset();

My IDE is telling me that typescript only interprets the properties defined in `data` as part of `this`, not those defined in `methods`. Have other folks run into this, and if so what did you do to fix it?

Note that this would work just fine in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether or not you have already solved this yourself considering it has been a few weeks:

Since you are using TypeScript, you do not need to define the methods inside the "methods" object. You can just define them directly on the class.